# Evaluate: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\right]^n\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

I am looking for the closed form, but I can't...

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\right]^n\mathrm dx=G(n)$$

$n\ge2$

We have: $G(2)=2$, $G(3)=\frac{3}{8}$,$G(4)=\frac{8}{81}$, $G(5)=\frac{15}{512}$, and so on,...

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}u^n e^{u(1-n)}\mathrm du\tag1$$

Is there an easy of calculating $(1)$

Comment: Take a look at gamma-function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}u^n e^{u(1-n)}\mathrm du = \frac{1}{(n-1)^{n+1}} \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{n} \;dt  = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{(n-1)^{n+1}} = \frac{n!}{(n-1)^{n+1}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Starting from
$$G(n) = \int_0^\infty u^n e^{u(1-n)}du$$

One has, by letting $(n-1)u=x \implies (n-1) du =dx$, then
\begin{align}
G &= \int_0^\infty\left( \frac{x}{n-1}\right)^ne^{-x}dx \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{(n-1)^{n+1}}
\end{align}